# Running VB.NET on Windows PE

Tags: .net-framework, vb.net, windows-pe

I made an app in Visual Basic. And I want to run it in Windows PE - the stock PE you can get from Microsoft, not any distro such as BartPE.
WindowsPE doesn't support .NET by default, but I think there has to be a way to install all libraries.
I'm using 32-bit version of Windows PE 4.0 (Based on Windows 8.0) but I can also use the newest Windows PE 10.0.14393.0. Should I? The priority is to get the VB.NET app running. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

This will work with any modern version of Windows PE (so the Windows 8 one is fine, as is the edition for Windows 10). I've personally used the [Windows 8.1 ADK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982) with success. In the feature selection stage of the installer, make sure you have *Deployment Tools* and of course WinPE.

Then you can run an appropriately modified version of this batch script as an administrator from the "Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment":

```
@echo off
set _=%CD%
set PF=C:\Program Files
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\" set PF=C:\Program Files (x86)
echo Preparing PE workspace...
call copype.cmd x86 scratch\ > nul
cd %_%
echo Mounting image...
dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:scratch\media\sources\boot.wim /index:1 /MountDir:scratch\mount > nul
echo Injecting WMI packages...
dism /image:scratch\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%PF%\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-WMI.cab" > nul
dism /image:scratch\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%PF%\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-WMI_en-us.cab" > nul
echo Injecting .NET packages...
dism /image:scratch\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%PF%\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-NetFX.cab" > nul
dism /image:scratch\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%PF%\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-NetFx_en-us.cab" > nul
echo Adding files...
REM: Add commands to copy in the appropriate files here
REM: Or insert a "pause" so you can manually do it in Explorer
echo Unmounting image...
dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:scratch\mount /Commit > nul
echo Finishing up...
move scratch\media\sources\boot.wim boot.wim > nul
rmdir /s /q scratch > nul
```

The `%PF%` stuff is there so it can automatically detect where the Windows Kits folder is, which depends on the bitness of the technician computer. If you use a different version of the ADK, change all the instances of `8.1` to the folder name of your kit. The important part is where it adds the WMI and .NET packages. (The .NET one depends on WMI.) The final `boot.wim` file produced will be able to run .NET applications that are the same bitness as the WinPE environment.

Comment: @PetrMolek Glad I could help! If my answer completely solved the problem, you can click the check mark next to it to indicate to future readers that this is the solution.